# Why does Powershell Start-Process not work when called from go (golang)?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, go

I wish to run a Windows batch script from go, under a different user to the user running the go program. The user running go has more privileges than the user that should run the batch script.

From go there are several options for executing a process under a different user on Windows, such as writing windows calls directly using the syscall package in go. I have not attempted this yet, but I have tried both using PsExec and also Powershell. Powershell is preferred since it comes installed as standard on Windows 2008 R2.

The following code demonstrates the problem I have. In the following demo, I run a batch script. This batch script calls a Powershell script directly, and then calls it from a go program. The results are different. The Powershell script outputs 3 files, yet when called from go, only outputs 2 files.

For the sake of completeness, I also show how the user was created.

C:\stackoverflow\demo.bat:

```
::::: create a new user for the demo :::::

:: first create a home directory
mkdir C:\Users\Tom
:: remove Users group
icacls C:\Users\Tom /remove:g Users
:: remove Everyone
icacls C:\Users\Tom /remove:g Everyone
:: create user Tom and set his home directory
net user Tom _Jerry123_ /add /expires:never /passwordchg:no /homedir:C:\Users\Tom /y
:: Give Tom access to his home directory
icacls C:\Users\Tom /grant:r Tom:(CI)F SYSTEM:(CI)F Administrators:(CI)F
:: give him access to Remote Desktop
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add Tom

::::: now call powershell directly :::::

powershell -command C:\stackoverflow\demo.ps1
:: show which files were created
dir C:\Users\Tom
:: cleanup
del /f /q C:\Users\Tom\*

::::: run the go version to do the same thing :::::

go run C:\stackoverflow\demo.go
:: compare results
dir C:\Users\Tom
:: cleanup
del /f /s /q C:\Users\Tom
rmdir /s /q C:\Users\Tom
:: delete user
net user Tom /delete
```

C:\stackoverflow\demo.ps1

```
write-output "test output" | out-file C:\Users\Tom\started.txt
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @("Tom",(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "_Jerry123_" -AsPlainText -Force))
Start-Process C:\stackoverflow\whoami.bat -WorkingDirectory C:\stackoverflow -Credential ($credentials) -Wait
write-output "test output" | out-file C:\Users\Tom\finished.txt
```

C:\stackoverflow\demo.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    run(exec.Command("PowerShell", "-Command", "C:\\stackoverflow\\demo.ps1"))
}

func run(cmd *exec.Cmd) {
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

C:\stackoverflow\whoami.bat:

```
whoami > C:\Users\Tom\whoami.txt
```

And now, the results - here you see when called from batch script, files started.txt, whoami.txt, finished.txt all get created. When called from go, only started.txt and finished.txt get created. Why is that?

Output:

```
C:\stackoverflow>demo.bat

C:\stackoverflow>mkdir C:\Users\Tom

C:\stackoverflow>icacls C:\Users\Tom /remove:g Users
processed file: C:\Users\Tom
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\stackoverflow>icacls C:\Users\Tom /remove:g Everyone
processed file: C:\Users\Tom
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\stackoverflow>net user Tom _Jerry123_ /add /expires:never /passwordchg:no /homedir:C:\Users\Tom /y
The command completed successfully.


C:\stackoverflow>icacls C:\Users\Tom /grant:r Tom:(CI)F SYSTEM:(CI)F Administrators:(CI)F
processed file: C:\Users\Tom
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\stackoverflow>net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add Tom
The command completed successfully.


C:\stackoverflow>powershell -command C:\stackoverflow\demo.ps1

C:\stackoverflow>dir C:\Users\Tom
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is CCD6-C9E7

 Directory of C:\Users\Tom

06/18/2015  06:36 AM    <DIR>          .
06/18/2015  06:36 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/18/2015  06:36 AM                28 finished.txt
06/18/2015  06:36 AM                28 started.txt
06/18/2015  06:36 AM                55 whoami.txt
               3 File(s)            111 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  16,489,889,792 bytes free

C:\stackoverflow>del /f /q C:\Users\Tom\*

C:\stackoverflow>go run C:\stackoverflow\demo.go
Done

C:\stackoverflow>dir C:\Users\Tom
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is CCD6-C9E7

 Directory of C:\Users\Tom

06/18/2015  06:36 AM    <DIR>          .
06/18/2015  06:36 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/18/2015  06:36 AM                28 finished.txt
06/18/2015  06:36 AM                28 started.txt
               2 File(s)             56 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  16,489,889,792 bytes free

C:\stackoverflow>del /f /s /q C:\Users\Tom
Deleted file - C:\Users\Tom\finished.txt
Deleted file - C:\Users\Tom\started.txt

C:\stackoverflow>rmdir /s /q C:\Users\Tom

C:\stackoverflow>net user Tom /delete
The command completed successfully.


C:\stackoverflow>
```

Comment: I see that "bytes free" counter is not changed between the two `dir` commands, while it should, as there were three files in the folder after running Powershell, and two after running Go. Therefore the file was created, although it's either not visible (check `attrib -r -h -s c:\users\tom\whoami.txt`) or is located elsewhere. Please search for the file(s) with name containing `whoami` after you run go command, probably there is an issue with permissions on the file, or folder redirection.

Comment: Thanks Vesper, this was a good idea. Unfortunately it is not the reason; the `attrib` command returned `File not found` and the file did not turn up in a search. I then did a quick test and created some small files, and the `bytes free` also did not change when running `dir` - so I think that might be a red herring. I guess `bytes free` is not always immediately updated.

Comment: Could it be that the scope of `go` makes PowerShell forget that .bat scripts are associated with `cmd /c`, whereas PowerShell invoked within a batch script maintains the association? Does it make any difference if you `Start-Process cmd.exe "/c c:\stackoverflow\whoami.bat" -otherargs`?  If not, does it make any difference to insert `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` at the top of demo.ps1?

Comment: Many thanks rojo, I tried both these suggestions, but unfortunately neither fixed it, and I still get the same results. I also experimented having a batch script to call Powershell, and then invoking the batch script from go rather than Powershell directly, but that also did not fix it. Thanks for you suggestion though.

Comment: To clarify, the powershell cmdlets in the demo.ps1 execute correctly, but some part of the Start-Process and/or batch file does not?

Comment: Also, do you have any extra folders in `C:\Users`? I'm noticing that when I run the script, it creates a `C:\Users\Tom.MyHostname`

Comment: Eris, to clarify the problem: demo.ps1 is called from demo.bat and also from demo.go. In both cases it executes. When called from demo.bat it generates 3 files, when called from demo.go it generates only 2. Above I present the output from invoking the powershell both ways, so you can see the difference in results. Hope this helps. Many thanks again for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

1. The user Tom cannot access the `C:\Stackoverflow` folder by default, in order for anything to run, I had to give Everyone access to Read/Execute items in that folder, else the start-process failed miserably
2. Add profilepath to the net user command. This prevented the extra folders being created that I mentioned in a comment:

   `net user Tom _Jerry123_ /add /expires:never /passwordchg:no /homedir:C:\Users\Tom /profilepath:C:\Users\Tom /y`
3. Replace the `Start-Process` line with:

   `Start-Process C:\stackoverflow\whoami.bat -WorkingDirectory C:\Users\Tom -Credential ($credentials) -Wait`

Why?

With the working directory set to C:\StackOverflow, the command interpreter that is executing the batch file finds the `whoami.bat` before the builtin, and all kinds of broken happens. Once I moved the working directory to Tom's folder, everything worked exactly as you wanted.

Alternative:

Don't name your batch files the same as builtin commands.

Comment: Many thanks Eris for the time you have taken to look into my question. Unfortunately I think it hasn't quite yet answered it for me.

Apologies, I hit enter too soon! Let me continue...

Comment: The changes you suggested didn't result in the go program generating the three files. Also the powershell script worked when called from the demo.bat file, so the change (1) to the user account cannot be necessary. Change (2) is useful, but not related to the problem described. Change (3) had no impact for me, and also in the demo.bat file the working directory is C:\stackoverflow, so equivalent to the go program, so does not explain the discrepancy. Many thanks.

Comment: The go script is being run as the admin user, the powershell script is run as the admin user. Only the batch file is run using `Start-Process` as the new user.